# How and Where to use Line Break in PS ISE

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, powershell-ise

I have a script that I will post down below, and the console feedback is kind of ugly, which I will also post below the script. I am wondering HOW and WHERE do I put a line break to ensure the console feedback I get looks nicer. I am using PowerShell ISE.

```
# Service Name and Server Name Variables 

$SvcName = 'LoneStar - MessageRouter',
'LoneStar - TransactionHandler'

$SvrName = 'HQDEVAPP004'

#Initialize variables:
[string]$WaitForIt = ""
[string]$Verb = ""
[string]$Result = "FAILED"
$svc = (get-service -computername $SvrName -name $SvcName)
Write-host "$SvcName on $SvrName is $($svc.status)"
Switch ($svc.status) {
    'Stopped' {
        Write-host "Starting $SvcName..."
        $Verb = "start"
        $WaitForIt = 'Running'
        $svc.Start()}
    'Running' {
        Write-host "Stopping $SvcName..."
        $Verb = "stop"
        $WaitForIt = 'Stopped'
        $svc.Stop()}
    Default {
        Write-host "$SvcName is $($svc.status).  Taking no action."}
}
if ($WaitForIt -ne "") {
    Try {  
        $svc.WaitForStatus($WaitForIt,'00:00:05')
    } Catch {
        Write-host "After waiting for 2 minutes, $SvcName failed to $Verb."
    }
    $svc = (get-service -computername $SvrName -name $SvcName)
    if ($svc.status -eq $WaitForIt) {$Result = 'SUCCESS'}
    Write-host "$Result`: $SvcName on $SvrName is $($svc.status)"
}
```

This is what the console feedback looks like:

```
SUCCESS: LoneStar - MessageRouter LoneStar - TransactionHandler on HQQAAPP004 is Running Running
```

I'd like for it to look more like:

```
SUCCESS: 

LoneStar - MessageRouter on HQQAAPP004 is Running

LoneStar - TransactionHandler on HQQAAPP004 is Running
```

Comment: I'd start by adding `\n` to the end of each of the strings that you want a line break after.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Oooh, I see. I'm still very new to this site and posting on forums altogether. I was under the impression that if I found multiple posts helpful to me, I could mark multiple as the "Answer." I did notice yesterday that your answer was completely gone from that previous post. I apologize, as I was unaware. I hope you enjoy your day whether you change your mind or not about helping, thanks!

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle But both were very helpful. The previous one was short and to the point, and yours was very detailed and introduced me to the idea of making arrays for these type of situations, although it took me just a little bit longer to figure out how to utilize what you gave me since I'm still learning. Again, very grateful for your answer, as I feel like you take your time and put a lot of effort into writing your answers. I apologize once again. Keep on puking out that good ol' IT knowledge!

Comment: @Zero596 I think Frank's answer will give you a quick and easy to understand solution as well by simply adding that. My idea is a little different but not sure if it'll be easier, etc. I'll give it a bit and follow up to see what the status is here.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Thank you for your understanding, and sorry about that confusion. I will be sure that any future answers you give me that help me, I will Accept it and keep it that way. But I appreciate the future help! Looking forward to the insight and knowledge you provide.

Comment: @Zero596... You did nothing wrong. You are free to accept and then unaccept a different and better answer as you please. Did you by chance test the backtick `n` as per Frank's comment?  The upvote thing is good enough for any answer you find anywhere that you find helpful. Voting is not required but important to some people more than others. I try to write quality content in my answers that also teaches people things at the same time. Please let me know about the backtick with the n as per the other comment. I handle this a little differently when it happens to me though to resolve.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle So the backslash n wasn't working for me. It kept thinking I was wanting to do something with a directory. Or maybe I should've tried the forward slash n. Haven't had too much time to work on it or try anything but the back tick n did work. My only issue is trying to figure out where to put these to make the console feedback look nicer. But the back tick n indeed causes a line break. So I'll be working with it more today since I have more time. I'll let you know what I come up with! Sorry for the late responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new line by simply adding `n inside the string.

The issue seems to be that

```
$SvcName = 'LoneStar - MessageRouter',
'LoneStar - TransactionHandler'

#Here the $SvcNAme just prints as a single string 'LoneStar - MessageRouter LoneStar - TransactionHandler'

Try this:
Write-host "$Result`:`n`n $($SvcName[0]) on $SvrName is $($svc[0].status) `n`n$($SvcName[1]) on $SvrName is $($svc[1].status)"
```

Comment: $SvcName is an array containing 2 strings, by adding [0] and [1] we just call out one of them by its number.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Since in the learning phases of PowerShell but trying my best. This made great sense! I appreciate your help and I will retain that information for any other Array I create.